# How to call a Function in a string in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have a MS Access database in which I want to call a function which has today's date in a string as below. I am trying to put today's date in the subject line and the email body on the new email which will be created. Any ideas to achieve this?

```
Private Sub Command_Click()

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ThisDay As Date

ThisDay = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yy")    

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objEmail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = "Daily Email Processed " *(Thisday)
    .Body = "Hi," + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "Please find below the number of Emails processed for the  " + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "Email Count = " + vbNewLine + "O Count = "
    .Attachments.Add ""
    .Attachments.Add ""
    .Display        
End With

Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `Format()` returns a string, so `Dim ThisDay As String`.  Do you have other issues with that code?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Ok thanks for that but how will I call it in .Subject = "Daily email count" & Thisday& like this or what?

Comment: It is usually simpler to compose a `mailto://..` url with subject, body, recipents etc, and let the OS resolve a mail client to edit the message before sending. See http://email.about.com/od/mailtoemaillinks/a/mailto_elements.htm, and make sure you `UrlEncode` all data before adding to the url.

Comment: since i am doing this in ms access i am sorry but i don't know how to do the way you are telling me :(        @ja72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You intend to store a `Format()` expression in your *ThisDay* variable.  `Format()` returns a string, so declare the variable to match.

```vb
'Dim ThisDay As Date
Dim ThisDay As String
```

After you've loaded the formatted date string into *ThisDay*, you can concatenate it to the rest of the subject line.

```vb
'.Subject = "Daily Email Processed " *(Thisday)
.Subject = "Daily Email Processed " & Thisday
```